# Vaadin - layout size to fit components

Tags: java, vaadin

I have following situation: *VerticalLayout* with *Labels* inside it. (this layout is interrior of popup)
When I'm building the application I don't know lengths of the labels - the label contents are queried from database.

Is there any way to tell this *VerticalLayout* to have width enough to fit all labels without breaking them, but not bigger? I don't want labels to break, but I also don't want to have empty space in the popup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Vaadin labels have a width of 100%. You'll want to change that to "undefined", and the same for the VerticalLayout : In both cases `setWidth(null)` or `setWidth(-1, UNIT_PIXELS)`